# soap client & wsdl: TIdHTTP or HTTPRIO

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, indy

I need to make a SOAP client application in Delphi and received WSDL and XSD files that describe the services.

I was wondering what's the recommended to achieve this in Delphi:
a) with TIdHTTP or 
b) through HTTPRIO (via Embarcadero's WSDL importer).

Response speed is very important in this application.

Comment: I've used the HTTPRIO and it works fine.  As far as which one is faster, you'll probably have to put together your own test and test both.